# CSS3 background-image texture with gradient does not working

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

I set this and it works.

```
background: #F5F5F5;
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'); /* fallback */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #FFF); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #FFF); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #FFF); /* IE10 */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #FFF); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url('/images/texture.png'),         linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #FFF); /* W3C */
```

but sometimes I got this error message:

`File does not exist: /var/www/html/site.com/images/texture.png), linear-gradient(top, , referer: site.com`

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path ('/images/texture.png') to the image in your CSS. This is most likely causing the problem if you are using sub-folders in your site because the relative path to the image file is no longer valid from within the sub-folder.

For example, if you have a page in your site in a sub-folder called "Accounts" then the path to the image from a page in the sub-folder will be '/Accounts/images/texture.png', which is obviously not correct and will generate a File Does Not Exist error.

It is easy to avoid this problem by using a full URL (http://) and (www.site.com/images/texture.png) as the path to the image in your CSS. This way your application always knows exactly where to find the image, no matter where your CSS file resides or how many sub folders deep a page it.